# zip4j zipping for files and folders in java

Tags: java, zip

I wish to create a zip program in Java, which zip files and folders let say structure like this -

- folder-one/
- folder-one/one.txt
- folder-one/two.mp3
- folder-one/three.jpg
- folder-two/
- folder-two/four.doc
- folder-two/five.rtf
- folder-two/folder-three/
- folder-two/folder-three/six.txt

I used zip4j open source, I have collected all the files (with absolute path) in one list then given it to zip but it is zipping files only as in my.zip -

- one.txt
- two.mp3
- three.jpg
- four.doc
- five.rtf
- six.txt

How can I preserve same structure on zipping and unzipping as it was on local earlier. Please suggest if any other open source can help me to zip/unzip in same structure files and folders like other windows zip programs.

Code is below --

```
public class CreateZipWithOutputStreams {

    ArrayList filesToAdd = new ArrayList();

    public void CreateZipWithOutputStreams(String sAbsolutePath) {


        ZipOutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {

            ArrayList arrLocal = exploredFolder(sAbsolutePath);


            outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\ZipTest\\CreateZipFileWithOutputStreams.zip")));

            ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();

            parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);


            parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);

            parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);

            parameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);


            parameters.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);


            parameters.setPassword("neelam");


            for (int i = 0; i < arrLocal.size(); i++) {
                File file = (File) arrLocal.get(i);


                outputStream.putNextEntry(file, parameters);

                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    outputStream.closeEntry();
                    continue;
                }


                inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] readBuff = new byte[4096];
                int readLen = -1;

                while ((readLen = inputStream.read(readBuff)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(readBuff, 0, readLen);
                }

                outputStream.closeEntry();

                inputStream.close();
            }

             outputStream.finish();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList exploredFolder(String sAbsolutePath) {
        File[] sfiles;
        File fsSelectedPath = new File(sAbsolutePath);
        sfiles = fsSelectedPath.listFiles();
        if (sfiles == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < sfiles.length; j++) {
            File f = sfiles[j];
            if (f.isDirectory() == true) {
                exploredFolder(f.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                filesToAdd.add(f);

            }
        }
        return filesToAdd;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CreateZipWithOutputStreams().CreateZipWithOutputStreams("c:\\ZipTest");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so first the code that is attached is supposed to work the way it is because the `exploredFolder(String absolutePath)` method is returning the "files to add" which in turn is being used by the `CreateZipWithOutputStreams()` method to create a single layered(flat) zip file.

What needs to be done is looping over the individual folders and keep adding them to the `ZipOutputStream`.

Please go through the link below and you will find the code snippet and detailed explaination.

Let me know if that helps!

http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/java-io/973-how-work-zip-files-java.html

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have to use  zipFile.createZipFileFromFolder(sAbsolutePath, parameters, true, 10485760) method of zip4j. Now its work fine. Can you please let me know the way to validate a zip file whether it is correctly zipped with accurate contents or not?

Comment: @NeelamSharma i think you need to close this question and open a new one :)     Also in the new question let me know what exactly are you trying to validate a.The presence of certain files ?   b.Whether it is corrupt or not ?

Comment: @NeelamSharma please close the question with whatever resolution code you would please .    :)    It helps ...